# many start commands batch in the same window

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window

I would like to start 3 commands in the same window.

For now I have this batch but there are 3 different windows at each command.

```
start /d "c:\Program Files\myfolder" cmd /k cscript A 
timeout /t 6 >nul
start /d "c:\Program Files\myfolder" cmd /k cscript B
timeout /t 6 >nul
start /wait /d "c:\PProgram Files\myfolder" cmd /k cscript C
```

What should I modify to have only one window? thanks

Comment: With so little information,are you expecting us to guess? I'll start, by saying **everything**; so perhaps: 1. `@CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\myfolder" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF`, 2. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "A.vbs"`, 3. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "B.vbs"`, 4. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "C.vbs"`, 5. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1`.

Comment: Using the `START` command to execute `CMD.EXE` to run `CSCRIPT.EXE` to launch another script makes no logical sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What about replacing the first line by the line `@cd /D "C:\Program Files\myfolder" || exit /B`, replacing the second line by `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo A`, replacing the third line by `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo B`, replacing the fourth line by `@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo C` and deleting the last line? Do you wonder why I suggest nearly the same as Compo? Well, same requirements result usually in similar code.

Comment: It works super fine thanks a lot. I used the Mofi solution. Indeed I was using to many commands and this way is OK. What I wanted to accomplish is to open a command prompt in the "myfolder " directory and then apply some script .VBS                                                 
   
.

@cd /d "c:\Program Files\MyFolder" || exit /b
timeout /t 4 >nul
@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo A.VBS 
timeout /t 4 >nul
@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo B.VBS
timeout /t 4 >nul
@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo C.VBS

Comment: Technically you've used both of our commernts, however, there is something you've missed in your resulting code, which I'd advise you to use, _(and it's already shown in my comment)_. Please do not invoke commands without providing their paths and extensions, it is lazy, assumes that no changes have been made to the `%Path%` or `%PATHEXT%` variables, and takes a little longer too, _(because the system would need to iterate through the values in those variables to locate the files first)_. Your `timeout /t 4 >nul` lines should look like this, `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 4 1>NUL`.

Comment: ok thanks for the advise. I added @echo off at the begining and the line with timeout is now resolved

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run a .bat file by changing the directory like so, `cd C:\PATH\TO\DIRECTORY\WITH\FILE`, then use `call (file name here)`. This should work assuming that all the files are in the same directory, if not you'll just have to change the directory for each `call` method. If my code doesn't seem very helpful, check this page out https://superuser.com/a/1062322

### Example Code

---

```
@echo off
cd PATH\TO\FILE\DIRECTORY
call FILE NAME
echo The file (file name here) has run!
pause
```

---

this code will make a call to the file and pause the terminal to keep it opened. You can take this code and make as many calls/cd's as you like. I hope this helped, If it doesn't work, please tell me what doesn't work and I'll try to fix it. Have a nice day :)